# Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function when using a jQuery plugin in Wordpress

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress

This is my script:

```
 $( "#top" ).click(function() {
  $( "#mid" ).slideDown( "slow", function() {
    // Animation complete.
  });

});
```

When I run the script website and receive this error does not work.

http://i62.tinypic.com/23m8zs7.jpg

I guess because it does not work ... you can help me to solve error please?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

jQuery is included with WordPress by default [in no-conflict mode](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script#jQuery_noConflict_Wrappers). In `noConflict()` mode, the global `$` shortcut for jQuery is not available, so you need to use:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    // Inside of this function, $() will work as an alias for jQuery()
    // and other libraries also using $ will not be accessible under this shortcut

    $( "#top" ).click(function() {
      // etc.
    });
});
```

Comment: jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
   
    $( "#top" ).click(function() {
      $( "#mid" ).slideDown( "slow", function() // etc.
    });
});

Comment: I put this script in script.js and doesn`t work...it`s incredible

Comment: What do you mean it "doesn't work"? What error are you getting now?

Comment: Unexpected Token at line 7 "}"..I tried to brace it does not work

Comment: You're missing an opening brace `{`. This is a different question. Please close up this one, and ask another if you're still experiencing the problem after fixing the syntax error.